# Dagger 2 - Understanding the different ways of doing field & method injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I understand that constructor injection should be preferred whenever possible, but for theoretical understanding, I want to learn more about field and method injection.

Method injection apparently is very rare, and according to Jake Wharton, the only use-case for it is when you have to pass an instance of your dependent object to the dependency (because it might be not fully instantiated in the constructor yet).

Example for method injection:

```
@Inject

public void enableStreaming(Streaming streaming) {

    streaming.register(this);

}
```

The **field** & **method** injection process into a dependent object can be triggered in 2 ways:

1. Either **in combination with constructor injection**, in which case
   it is executed automatically after the constructor ran (no need to call `inject` on a component). This is what is happening in the example
   above (I omitted the constructor, imagine it as being `@Inject` annotated)
2. **Without constructor injection**, when the object is already instantiated.
   In this case, we need a members-injection method where
   we pass the object. The fields/method will then be injected when we
   call `component.inject(object)` This is most commonly used for
   field-injection in activities and fragments.

What I am asking for, are examples for the opposite cases.

1. Do you have examples for when **field** injection is combined with
   constructor injection?
2. Do yo you have examples for when **method** injection is **not** combined
   with constructor injection (and therefore needs an explicit `inject` call)?
3. For both cases, I would like to know if there are situations when
   the `component.inject()` method is called from the outside or from within the object and what are use-cases for this. Is there ever a
   scenario where we call

   `ExampleObject exampleObject = new ExampleObject();
   component.inject(exampleObject);`

to execute field or method injection on exampleObject?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have published or official examples handy, but all of the situations you described work fine. It is unusual for field injection to be combined with constructor injection, because the fields are necessarily non-`final` to work with field injection where they could be final if passed through a constructor. It is less-unusual to see method injection without constructor injection, for similar self-registration cases to the `enableStreaming` method you wrote above, but that is still somewhat of an unusual use-case.

Though field and method injection may take place within the method or class being injected, this would necessitate receiving a specific Component instance or a `MembersInjector<T>` for your class `T`, which is at least as much trouble to call as `component.inject(exampleObject)` in your third example above. After all, the whole point of dependency injection is to allow the caller to control the class's dependencies, so it is arguably a weakening of DI for the owning class to take control of whether and how its dependencies are provided.

The only cases I can think of where a class would manage its own injection is if your class wanted to conditionally inject itself—`if (BuildOptions.FEATURE_X_ENABLED) { injector.inject(this); }`—but many other patterns spring to mind that would manage that type of case better.